# jq conditional processing on multiple files

Tags: json, jq

I have multiple json files:

**a.json**

```
{
  "status": "passed",
  "id": "id1"
}
{
  "status": "passed",
  "id": "id2"
}
```

**b.json**

```
{
  "status": "passed",
  "id": "id1"
}
{
  "status": "failed",
  "id": "id2"
}
```

I want to know which id was passed in `a.json` and which is failed now in `b.json`.

**expected.json**

```
{
  "status": "failed",
  "id": "id2"
}
```

I tried something like:

```
jq --slurpfile a a.json --slurpfile b b.json -n '$a[] | reduce select(.status == "passed") as $passed (.; $b | select($a.id == .id and  .status == "failed"))'
```

`$passed` is supposed to contain the list of passed entry in `a.json` and  `reduce` will merge all the objects for which the id matches and are `failed`.

However it does not produce the expected result, and the documentation is kind of limited.

How to produce `expected.json` from `a.json` and `b.json` ?

Comment: post that *the expected result*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your filter produces the error

```
jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot index array with string "id"
```

I suspect this is because you wrote `$b` instead of `$b[]` and `$a.id` instead of `$passed.id`.  Here is my guess at what you intended to write:

```
  $a[] 
| reduce select(.status == "passed") as $passed (.; 
   $b[] | select( $passed.id == .id and .status == "failed")
  )
```

which produces the output

```
null
{
  "status": "failed",
  "id": "id2"
}
```

You can filter away the `null` by adding `| values` e.g.

```
  $a[] 
| reduce select(.status == "passed") as $passed (.; 
   $b[] | select( $passed.id == .id and .status == "failed")
  )
| values
```

However you don't really need `reduce` here.  A simpler way is just:

```
   $a[]
 | select(.status == "passed") as $passed
 | $b[]
 | select( $passed.id == .id and .status == "failed")
```

If you intend to go further with this I would recommend a different approach: first construct an object combining `$a` and `$b` and then project what you want from it.  e.g.

```
reduce (($a[]|{(.id):{a:.status}}),($b[]|{(.id):{b:.status}})) as $v ({};.*$v)
```

will give you

```
{
  "id1": {
    "a": "passed",
    "b": "passed"
  },
  "id2": {
    "a": "passed",
    "b": "failed"
  }
}
```

To convert that back to the output you requested add

```
 | keys[] as $id
 | .[$id]
 | select(.a == "passed" and .b == "failed")
 | {$id, status:.b}
```

to obtain

```
{
  "id": "id2",
  "status": "failed"
}
```

Comment: Indeed it works. I was wondering if the `select` condition could be embedded in the reduce clause? Something like: `reduce ... as $v ({};.*$v | select(.a=="passed" and .b=="passed))`. However I couldn't make that run. I'm not sure of what's going on in that clause exactly.

Comment: `.*$v` is using [Object Multiplication](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Multiplication,division,modulo:*,/,and%) to merge each temporary object from `$a` and `$b` into one collected object.  If you wanted to put the condition in there you could but it might be easier to use an explicit `if` instead of a `select`.  For example: `reduce (($a[]|{(.id):{a:.status}}),($b[]|{(.id):{b:.status}})) as $v ({};.*$v| ($v|keys[0]) as $id| if .[$id].a == "passed" and .[$id].b == "passed" then del(.[$id]) else . end)`

Comment: Thanks @jq170727! Do you have a good source of documentation / training for jq to help grapple with all these subtleties? The official doc is a little light and the rest is usually a bunch of blog post with one liners...

Comment: Note this follows some details of your original question – slurping into two arrays `$a` and `$b` – but if this is as complex as your logic gets and you don't anticipate doing more complex stuff with those arrays I'd recommend [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022613/8379597)'s approach over this one.

Comment: Re docs: I have found the [jq source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/tree/master/src) helpful in learning, especially [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq).  There is also a lot of good information in the [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) and on [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Jq).  They are well worth your time if you want to learn more.  I have also found [JSON like a boss](https://www.slideshare.net/btiernay/jq-json-like-a-boss?qid=84235065-f3c2-4298-a381-819c9e5d5998) good too.

Answer (score 1):

The following solutions to the problem are oriented primarily towards efficiency, but it turns out that they are quite straightforward and concise.

For efficiency, we will construct a "dictionary" of ids of those who have passed in a.json to make the required lookup very fast.

Also, if you have a version of jq with `inputs`, it is easy to avoid "slurping" the contents of b.json.

#### Solution for jq 1.4 or higher

Here is a generic solution which, however, slurps both files:

Invocation (note the use of the -s option):

```
jq -s --slurpfile a a.json -f passed-and-failed.jq b.json
```

Program:

```
([$a[] | select(.status=="passed") | {(.id): true}] | add) as $passed
| .[] | select(.status == "failed" and $passed[.id])
```

That is, first construct the dictionary, and then emit the objects in b.json that satisfy the condition.

#### Solution for jq 1.5 or higher

Invocation (note the use of the -n option):

```
jq -n --slurpfile a a.json -f passed-and-failed.jq b.json
```

`INDEX/2` is currently available from the `master` branch, but is provided here in case your jq does not have it, in which case you might want to add its definition to `~/.jq`:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
```

The solution now becomes a simple two-liner:

```
INDEX($a[] | select(.status == "passed") | .id; .) as $passed
| inputs | select(.status == "failed" and $passed[.id])
```

Comment: This is definitely the best approach if this is the extent of the problem.